# Excel: List of links (Contents) on Sheet1 to filter detailed data on Sheet2

Tags: hyperlink, filter, excel-formula, filtering

Have a list of links on Sheet1 that ideally will work as a Contents or Overview Page.

When one of the links on Sheet1 is clicked, user is then navigated to Sheet2 filtering by what was just clicked on Sheet1.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

[Have added an image of desired outcome](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1K3pfpnrERwY2RzOWlvaWpLQVU&authuser=0)

Kind regards,
Joel

Comment: I don't think so. You could do this a thousand ways in VBA but not without them. You could define a function that pinpoints the given sheet's selection's top left cell or you could store the range as a global variable and reference them in a worksheet change event.

Comment: hello, maybe you can take a look at this [LINK](http://trumpexcel.com/2015/01/dynamic-excel-filter/) where it is shown how to create dynamic filter.